# How is electric field lines for a negative particle and a plane

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, charge

How is electric field lines for a negative particle and a  plane? (plane doesn't have any charge and it has thickness) does it like the following picture or not? (the picture is a little bit exaggerated and the particle is drawn bigger than it is)

I know the direction of one of lines is not right. DO NOT consider it.
[image]

Comment: I know the direction of one of lines is not right. DO NOT consider it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct. It should look like the classic image charge solution, the lower half of a dipole.